# How to write without overwrite in Qfile?

Tags: qt, qfile

Hi guys I have this code but it just overwrite the file. How can I just add text to the file?

```
 QFile file("E:/Qt/Qt codes/txt file/file");
 if(!file.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text)){ 
       QMessageBox::warning(this,"Title","File not open.");
 }
 QTextStream out(&file);
 QString text = ui->plainTextEdit_2->toPlainText();
 out << text;
 file.flush();
 file.close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set flag `QFile::Append`

`QFile` inherits `QIODevice`.

here is doc.[QIODevice Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html)